# Convert unix timestamp to avro and store it in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, avro

Avro schema:

```
{
  "name": "Entity",
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "com.foobar.entity",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "attribute",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "value",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "timestamp",
      "type": { "type": "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-micros" }
    }
  ]
}
```

The source timestamp is in Unix format with milli second precision.

When I put such records into BigQuery I get values like `1970-01-19 01:18:19.415 UTC` in the BigQuery data preview. However the value I stored is `1559899418` which is `Friday, 7. June 2019 09:23:38`. Any ideas why?

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro#logical_types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your timestamp is off by a factor 1000. Indeed, `1559899418` corresponds to `Friday, 7. June 2019 09:23:38`, but that's second-precision ([Unix timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com)), not millisecond.
And `1559899` (one thousandth of 1559899418) does indeed correspond to `1970-01-19 01:18:19`

Comment:  thanks for pointing this out. So in the end I did timestamp*1000*1000 and now BigQuery shows the correct date.