# Import a unix timestamp in seconds from Avro to the right timestamp in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, avro

I want to import data stored in AVRO format from GCS to Bigquery.

The source timestamp is in Unix format with second precision (e.g : 1572534049), however BQ requires it to be in milli-second or micro-second precision to use the logical type and convert it to the right TIMESTAMP (I currently get values in 1970-XX-XX instead of 2021-XX-XX).

I know my problem is similar to the following thread :
[Convert unix timestamp to avro and store it in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56492249/convert-unix-timestamp-to-avro-and-store-it-in-bigquery)

However, I can't multiply the column by 1000 in the AVRO files since they are retrieved from somewhere else then stored on a regular basis. It seems that I can't add a *1000 in the table schema definition either.

If there is no direct method, I will simply import the AVRO with the unix timestamp as an integer in an intermediate table, then output an other table with the expected columns through a query, but this isn't the most convenient.

edit : added example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out following solution to achieve desired requirements.

Step 1: Load data to Bigquery in same format as available over GCS.
Step 2: Create a [View](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views) over recently table and apply Date transformations in that view, going further always refer View for data.

Alternate solution:-
Step 1: Load data to Bigquery in same format as available over GCS.
Step 2: Create a [function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators) for Date transformation and apply function on Unix format date, before you call data.

It will work for your requirement.